# Android - file permissions

Tags: android, passwords, file-permissions

Is it possible to set file permissions for certain files and folders in Android? Or possibility to open the file on password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to set file permissions for certain files and folders in Android?

It is usually not needed for files on internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`) and is not possible on classic external storage (e.g., `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`).

> Or possibility to open the file on password?

No.

Comment: If you have some private notes or photos and you want that only you can view them, it's needed. I'm interested in some settings (not programming) e.g. rwx (similarly as in linux).

Comment: But there should be some possibility of access restriction. E.g. to zip the file with password and unzip it. Or not?

Comment: You'd have to do the encryption, prompt for password, decryption yourself. Android doesn't provide such canned functionality - you'd have to hook up the parts yourself.

Comment: @xralf: "If you have some private notes or photos and you want that only you can view them, it's needed." -- not really, as filesystem security is not the typical way this problem is solved in any mobile OS worth mentioning. "I'm interested in some settings (not programming)" -- if you are not interested in programming, you are on the wrong site. Try http://android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Is it possible to add READ_WRITE permissions to a file on external Storage in Android?